# Angular add ng-show inside ng-if?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I want this input to only show a property is true per the ng-if. The current code is:

```
<input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-if="ppt.Globals.hasDebitCard" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 2 ? -1 : 2)"  value="outstanding swipes">
```

Can I somehow add a ng-show inside of that ng-if expression and if so, then how? I thought maybe something like:

```
ng-if="ppt.Globals.hasDebitCard ? ng-show='true'"
```

Comment: Cannot get it to work with the one way. Ideas please?

Comment: It seems your purpose is wrong. Do you know what ng-if does and what ng-show does? if ng-if is false the element won't render and if it's true it'll be visible. Why would you want to combine both of them? ng-show tells if the element is css visible or not..

Answer (score 0):

You sure can! Here's an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller("myCtrl", [function(){
      this.isOn = "on";
      this.isChecked = true;
    }]);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as VM">
    <div ng-if="VM.isOn == 'on'" ng-show="VM.isChecked">
      Hi there
    </div>
    <div>ng-show: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="VM.isChecked" /></div>
    <div>ng-if:
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" ng-model="VM.isOn" value="on" />On
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" ng-model="VM.isOn" value="off" />Off
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So am cofused a bit further. Trying this: <input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-if=" {{ ppt.Globals.hasDebitCard ? ng-show : ng-hide }} " ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 2 ? -1 : 2)"  value="outstanding swipes"> But no avail.I believe I understand their differences and when to use, but not 100%, hence why asking here>